Preventing swiping on a wearable device using Jetpack compose
How do I prevent the dismissal of a wearable app (by swiping) that is written in Jetpack compose
I am considering using SwipeDismissFrameLayout (Which will be in an XML file),is there a way to go about this in Jetpack compose

Please edit your question to include a [mre].

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I implemented this with touch-listeners. In my case i use jetpack compose, but i added it to my existing layout bindings.
I still wanted to be able to catch clicks or to allow swipe. i get the touch events and calculate the distance.
IMPORTANT: you need to return true! otherwise the events will be handled from the system and your swipe will dismiss your app.
the mainlayout is full screen of course so it catches all the touches. It is a BoxInsetLayout which contains a ComposeView.
I'm not sure if you have touch listener in pure compose.
val maxInnerDistance = radius * 0.65
val maxOuterDistance = radius * 0.75
binding.mainLayout.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
when (event.action) {
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
        touchX = event.x
        touchY = event.y
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
         if (abs(touchX - event.x) > maxInnerDistance || abs(touchY - event.y) > maxInnerDistance) {
            //this is a swipe -> ignore or allow
         } else {
            //this is a click -> do something with it
         }
    }
true
}


Though I didn't try this out but perhaps it could be helpful to someone. Thank you for your answer @Veit .

I was able to achieve this by adding the code below to the theme assigned to Activity in the manifest. Hence there was no need for SwipeDismissFrameLayout.
<item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>

